# How do you change a UIStepper's value: Double outside of its @IBAction?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Within the @IBAction you just change the `value` property, but what about outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stepper does not have a `text` property. It has a `value` property, which is how you change it's value.

You need to set up an `IBOutlet` to your stepper:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myStepper: UIStepper!
```

and when you want to set its value:

```
myStepper.value = 6
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `value` and mistakenly wrote `text` since I was thinking of a `UIStepper` used in conjunction with a `UILabel`. This still answers my question, thanks.